# Cant get javascript to create links correctly from XML list

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Im trying to create a HTML table with links from a XML file using javascript. The html tbale works fine but when it comes to the link creation it seems the links only have the first word of my string  in the link. IF i do an alert(String) command i get the full string but as soon as i try to make an HTML LINK it only adds the first word.

Example:

Base link: http://kat.ph/usearch/{SEARCH FIELD GOES HERE}
String output from XML List : "Hello Sir"

Actual Output as link (without quotes):  **"http://kat.ph/usearch/Hello"** 
Expected output as link (without quotes): **"http://kat.ph/usearch/Hello Sir"**

Code is below

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","playlist.xml",false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

                document.write("<table border='1'>");
                var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("void");
                for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                { 
                    document.write("<tr><td>");
                    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    document.write("</td><td>");
                    //alert(x[i].getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); just testing to see what i get here
                    // document.write("<a href=http://www.kat.ph/usearch/" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ">"+"KAT.PH"+"</a>");
                    document.write("<a href='" + "http://www.kat.ph/usearch/" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "'>" + "KAT.PH" + "</a>"); 

                    document.write("</td></tr>");  

                }
                document.write("</table>");
            </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried [encodeURI](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.3.3) for entire the entire URL or [encodeURICoomponent](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.3.4) for parts of it as appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant have spaces in the URI (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp).  What you can do is encode it:

```
var term = x[i].getElementsByTagName("string")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var uri = "http://www.kat.ph/usearch/" + term;

document.write("<a href='" + encodeURI(uri) + "'>" + "KAT.PH" + "</a>");
```